# Is it possible to programmatically determine if Opportunity Teams is enabled?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, canvas, opportunity-teams

We have a Salesforce Managed Package that contains a Connected App with an Aura Component Bundle. Is there a programmatic way for for me to determine whether the tenant my Package is installed has Opportunity Teams activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect this by checking for the existence of `OpportunityTeamMember`. You can check this by Apex quite easily:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) public static Boolean isOpportunityTeamEnabled() {
  return Type.forName('Schema','OpportunityTeamMember') != null;
}
```

You can decide from there what to do from there. Note that using `OpportunityTeamMember` as a hard reference (e.g. `OpportunityTeamMember record = new OpportunityTeamMember()` in Apex code) will force your Managed Package to have a dependency on having this feature enabled. You'll need to use [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) to avoid this hard dependency.

Comment: Thank you - just what I was looking for!